# Python: download file from webpage, ashx

Tags: python, download, urllib2, ashx

On [this](https://www.animasgr.it/EN/Products/Scheda/Anima-Visconteo#cl=A&scheda=quot) webpage there is an "Export to Excel" button.
The command associated with this link should be:

https://www.animasgr.it/IT/Prodotti/Quotazioni-e-Performance/_layouts/15/GetExcel.ashx?type=QuoteFondo&code=A60A&i=03.06.1985&f=27.10.2016

How can I call this command from a Python script to dowload the file?
What I tried is:

```
response = urllib2.urlopen(https://www.animasgr.it/IT/Prodotti/Quotazioni-e-Performance/_layouts/15/GetExcel.ashx?type=QuoteFondo&code=A60A&i=03.06.1985&f=27.10.2016)

In [12]: response
Out[12]: <addinfourl at 4504653336 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x10cf9e550>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **requests** module:

```
import requests

url_file = 'https://www.animasgr.it/IT/Prodotti/Quotazioni-e-Performance/_layouts/15/GetExcel.ashx?type=QuoteFondo&code=A60A&i=03.06.1985&f=27.10.2016'
resp = requests.get(url_file)

with open('anyfilename.xls', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(resp.content)
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/